# Necessary and sufficient conditions for $f=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

We asumme the following theorem:

> **Theorem:** Let $G$ be a connected open set and $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function. Then the following are equivalent statements:
>
> - $f=0$.
> - There is $a\in G$ such that $f^{(n)}(a)=0$ for each $n\ge 0$.
> - $\{z\in G:f(z)=0\}$ has a limit point in $G$.

I would like to show that we actually must assume $G$ to be connected in the theorem. Otherwise it is false.

Can anyone help me to find an example? I thought on some elementary functions but it won't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sets $A = \{z:|z|< 1\}$ and $B = \{z:2< |z|< 3\}$ and define $f:A\cup B\to\Bbb C$  by $$f(z)=\begin{cases}0,&z\in A\\1,&z\in B\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very simple :)

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just take two disjoint open sets, $A$ and $B$. On one, you let $f$ be identically zero, and on the other, you make it something else. Given that "analytic" is a local property, the way $f$ acts on one set has absolutely no bearing on how it acts on a disconnected component and you may define your function piecewise.

It is worthy of note that applying familiar functions won't work here - it must be that $f$ is analytic on $A\cup B$ but not on $\mathbb C$ (as the theorem would then imply that it was identically zero on $\mathbb C$). So, a piecewise definition is going to be more or less necessary. Certainly, no function which is usually taken to be elementary will work, nor will any composition of such functions.